# How many $n$th roots does $0$ have?

Tags: terminology, roots

Do we say that $0$ has $n$ $n$th roots, all nondistinct, or only one?

I don't think it makes any difference, but I'm curious what the convention is.

Comment: I think it depends on who "we" are; in different contexts, people might adopt different conventions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terminology varies a bit between people and fields, but what I would say is that $x^n=0$ has one root (namely $0$) of *multiplicity* $n$.

If we explicitly say that we count that root "with multiplicity", of course, there are $n$ of it.

Comment: I prefer this answer compared to Mariano's; also, for clarity's sake (regarding variable terminology), consider the zero vector. We know it has zero magnitude but what about its direction? You could say $0^{\circ}$ or $360^{\circ}$ and it be a perfectly reasonable response I think. Just something to consider.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out about roots of numbers after doing polynomials and it really blew my mind! But I now see there isn't much of a conceptual difference between the two.

Comment: @induktio, in the case of the direction of the zero vector there is a problem: assigning it a direction, that is, trying to treat it just like other vectors in that respect, leads to problems. In the case of the OP this does not happen.

Comment: This must be the first time I disagree with you. OP didn’t ask for the roots of $X^n$, but the $n$-th roots of zero. Not the same thing, I would say. But to spend time on the distinction seems to me nugatory.

Comment: @Lubin: I had to look up "nugatory". If you think spending time on the distinction is "trivial, trifling or of little importance" (as Wiktionary says), then what are we actually disagreeing about?

Comment: Something trivial, trifling, or of little importance. If I had thought otherwise, I would have given my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As many as roots of the polynomial equation $X^n=0$, that is, $n$.

Comment: References for that convention?

Comment: The $n$th roots of a number $a$ are the roots of the polynomial equation $X^n=a$. The reference is to common sense and parsimony. It would introduce a gratuitous complication to count the roots of the polynomial $X^n$ in any way different from the way we count the roots of any other polynomial.

Comment: So, continuing from here we should say that $0$ has $n$ real roots, too?

Comment: Well, are the roots, counted with multiplicity, real? If yes, yes, and if no, no.

Comment: Every real number has unique real third root, except for 0, which has three. ;D

Comment: No. Every nonzero real number does.

Comment: One more try: I assume we agree that an $n$-th root of unity is defined as a root of $X^n = 1$.  How many $32$-th root of unity are there over $Z/2Z$?

Comment: $32$, all of them equal to $1$.

Comment: If it where not closed I would invite you to submit an answer to this MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58357/number-of-n-th-roots-of-unity-over-finite-fields that according to you apparently is answered incorrectly.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand why you are picking on this, and not on Henning's answer, seeing that the two answers have exactly the same content.

Comment: In any case, I have absolutely no interest in dragging on what is obviously a matter of convention.

Comment: The other answerer says it "has one root" and mentions that one might also adopt a different convention this is really not the same. The reason why I am picking on this is that I was honestly curious how serious you are regarding this convention. It is a pity that you seem not interested in a serious investigation about the merits of different conventions. Feel free to remove the comments.

Comment: The other anwer quite explicitly says that «If we explicitly say that we count that root "with multiplicity", of course, there are n of it.» I am of the oppositve convention, and explicitely say «distinct roots» when I want to drop duplicates. I am very serious, and cannot but wonder what could have given you any other idea.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments. I now did what I likely should have done right away namely write my own answer. (The comments here are possibly obsolete now; in any case I do not need them.)

Answer (score 1):

There is, as is visible, no universally agreed upon convention. However, I would argue in favor of considering by an large the number of $n$-th roots of an element $a$ (in some structure) the **cardinality of the set** of solutions of $X^n = a$, so that in the complex and real numbers, and in any other field, $0$ is the unique  root of $0$.

The alternative convention is arguably convenient over the complex numbers, however, already in the real numbers the situation is less clear (though one might still present reasonable arguments in its favor).

Yet roots are also considered in other structures.

- Roots of unity, so roots of $1$, in finite fields play an important role, as do for example quadratic residues; for the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) $0$ is treated separately, corresponding to the convention that it has a unique square-root modulo $p$, and typically when one wonders about the number of roots of unity in a finite field one will consider the cardinality of the set (see an [MO question on that subject](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58357/number-of-n-th-roots-of-unity-over-finite-fields)).
- Further, looking beyond fields, the situation become even more cumbersome for other conventions. For example in $Z/4Z$ we have $0$ and $2$ as square-roots of $0$. Should $0$ still be counted twice? Should $2$ also be counted twice, after all $(X+2)^2 = X^2$?
- Still further, it is common to consider roots of (certain) matrices. There is an infinitude of real $2 \times 2$ matrices whose square is the $0$-matrix. They are all square-roots of the $0$-matrix, among them one finds the $0$-matrix itself.

In each case, it seems the cardinality of the set of solutions makes some sense, while the assigning of multiplicities becomes rather more unclear (I might miss something though).

Comment: Counting roots in a non-domain or a noncommutative ring is problematic. In fact, the notion of root itself is problematic.

Comment: The notion of the square root of a matrix is, whether you consider it as problematic or not, pretty standard. It is true it is mainly considered restricted to positive definite matrices, however, this is orthogonal to the question at hand. Further, roots  are not only considered for domains but also for semigroups (likely mainly commutative and cancelative, that's true), where however there is not even a notion of polynomial. It still makes sense though to wonder if $X^n = a$ has a solution. Still further, recall things like functional roots.